# How to use the list files in a given directory via batch file without showing the full path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, dir

I have searched for this everywhere so I hope it has not already been asked, but I have a batch file where the user can write his / her own 'scripts' if you will.  When the batch file is ran for the first time it will make a directory under %appdata%\Mellow\Mango\scripts and these scripts will simply be .txt files.  Anyway...

I am trying to list the 'scripts' to the user by using `dir /b /s *.txt` and the output is `C:\Users\Tate\AppData\Roaming\Mellow\Mango\scripts\template.txt`

My question is, sorry if I got off-topic before, how to display only template.txt and not the full file path.  I simply would like to list all .txt files contained in the scripts folder.  Thanks in advanced!

Current Output:

```
C:\Users\Tate\AppData\Roaming\Mellow\Mango\scripts\template.txt
C:\Users\Tate\AppData\Roaming\Mellow\Mango\scripts\another_script.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
template.txt
another_script.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the /s

dir /b *.txt

That should do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  I could have swore I tried that before but I guess I only tried removing the /b and tried adding /x etc.  Works perfectly now! (:  Edit:  I probably should have looked up what the /letters even meant now that I think about it aha.

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  Glad I could help.